# Compiling .dproj files from command line

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am using Embarcadero Delphi XE2 and I've got a project that I want to compile from command line. I managed to do it with dcc32 on a .dpr, but I had to set some settings.

From what I think, the file .dproj has all the necessary paths and stuff so I wouldn't need to set those variables, so my question is:

Is it possible to compile a delphi command line project from a .dproj file?

Greetings.

Comment: also see this cool tool: https://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/01/18/dproj-changed-or-not-changed/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. It's actually very simple.

Use the `Windows Start` button to launch `Embarcadero RAD Studio XE2->RAD Studio Command Prompt`, which sets up the proper environmental variables and search path entries. Then switch to your project folder and simply type `MSBuild` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which will execute the compiler with the current project file.

If you have more than one .dproj file in the folder, just add it's name after `MSBuild`, as in `MSBuild MyMainProj.dproj`.

Comment: In a batch file you'd do call path\to\delphi\bin\rsvars.bat to set up the environment. Which cuts out the manual step of opening a RAD Studio command prompt.

Comment: @David, true. :-) It just asks about doing so from a command line, but I should have mentioned that as  well. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks man it worked like it should! (-author of the question)